# Emitting data via EventBus

Tags: vue.js, emit

I would like to emit some data from one component to the other (children components).
In my main.js I created: `export const Bus = new Vue({})`.
Then in my first child component ,I've got an input with v-model and I would like to pass that v-model.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <button type="button" @click="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { Bus } from './../main.js';
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit() {
        if(this.message !== ''){
          this.$router.push('location');
          Bus.$emit('name', this.message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My second component:

```
  import { Bus } from './../main.js';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        recievedMessage: ''
      }
    },
    created() {
      Bus.$on('name', (message) => {
        this.recievedMessage = message;
      })
    }
  }
```

Then I try to display passed data: `{{ recievedMessage }}`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set up a global EventHub in your main.js, the second component isn't listening because it **has not** been initialized in the whole Vuejs life-cycle.

However, if you intended on your child component being rendered within the parent then you will need to import the component into the parent.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="message" />
    <button type="button" @click="submit">Submit</button>
    <child-component /> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import ChildComponent from '@/components/ChildComponent'
  import { Bus } from './../main.js';
  export default {
    components:{
      ChildComponent
    }
    data () {
      return {
        message: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit() {
        if(this.message !== ''){
          this.$router.push('location');
          Bus.$emit('name', this.message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

***UPDATED***

**Child Component**

```
   <template>
     <div>{{recievedMessage}}</div>
   </template>
   <script>
    import { Bus } from './../main.js';
      export default {
        data() {
          return {
            recievedMessage: ''
          }
        },
        created() {
          Bus.$on('name', this.eventHandlerMethod)
        },
        methods: {
          eventHandlerMethod (message) {
             this.recievedMessage = message;
          }
        }
      }
   </script>
```

The listener is calling "eventHandlerMethod" which update the data instance.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the way for me. Actually I've got Vue Dev-Tools and it shows that data got passed, but I am not able to display it. So how do I initialize that 'second component' in life-cycle?

Comment: Doesn't work for  me unfortunately and I guess `(msg)` should be replaced with `(message)` but still the same.

Comment: @kabugh Could you share your project in a Plunk or Codepen?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/UwTxJggJsfVxQ8qCqsI0/ Here are all files needed, ignore `index.js` and `survey`, not sure how to delete it.